# Eclipse Flash Builder show Type-hierarchy for Actionscript files

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder, hierarchy

In eclipse, in the Java perspective, hitting <kbd>F4</kbd> opens the type hierarchy of the current folder. You can also right-click a Java file and select Open Type Hierarchy. (see on the [eclipse help page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-6.htm))

For some reason, this doesn't work in the flash builder plugin (flash perspective) when in ActionScript files (.as), neither with <kbd>F4</kbd> nor does it appear in the right-click context menu, even though some sites suggest it should work.

Is there any way to do this in flash builder or by installing any other plugin into Eclipse?
If not, is there any tool that can do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what functionality you're referring to, but I've noticed that sometimes different plugins can redirect key commands.  Is it possible that you have a plugin that is remapping the key for a different purpose?

Comment: This isn't the case. The functionality isn't there. It's not even in the context menu.

Comment: Flash builder does have an option from the navigate menu to "Open Type"; however I believe this is unrelated to the current folder.

Comment: I upvoted because i still use Flex, and i am surprised that non one sayed if it exists or not. I bet it doesn't exists, and it is too bad, because the class hierarchy is one of the basic of a Class information.

Comment: Since there is no better answer, here is my workaround: to find all super classes of an abstract class : select class name then right click and use : "Open hierarchy call" or ctrl alt H. The dependencies and extension usage are mixed in this view.